# XmlSerializer: Custom attribute for ignore element

Tags: c#, .net, xml

Is there way to XmlSerializer ignore some properties without using [XmlIgnore]?

What i want to achieve: I want to modify common models (used in many places I don't know) way that my serializer will ignore some properties; but existing serializers will work the same way as now.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the "ShouldSerializeMyPropertyName" convention: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/defining-default-values-with-the-shouldserialize-and-reset-methods

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Bar { get; set; }

    public bool ShouldSerializeBar()
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

That method can be made `virtual` and overridden by subclasses or driven as needed.

Beyond that, you can implement [`IXmlSerializable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable) but I suspect this could be more trouble than what its worth for your use case scenario.